# Socket.io: Socket Connections sometimes are null

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I usually use an array to store all connected clients in a socket server, but this time I decided to spice things up a bit and use an object rather than array.  Maybe this is the problem with a recent project of mine, but this is a close mockup to what I have running and it works almost always, but every now and then getusername() will return null.  I was wondering why, and I also included where this sort of behavior can occasionally crash my server.

```
const express = require(`express`);
const http = require(`http`);
const ioserver = require(`socket.io`);
const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);
const io = ioserver(server);

let sessions = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', socket =>{
    socket.on('login', (data)=>login(socket, db, data));
    socket.on('eventafterloggingin', (data)=>eventafterloggingin(socket, data));
    socket.on('disconnect', ()=>disconnect(socket));
});

const getusername = socket => {
    return Object.keys(sessions).find(key => sessions[key] === socket);
}

const login = (socket, db, data)=>{
    //do a bunch of sanitization, db querying, data validation, etc
    //...

    //...
    //if all passes through:
    sessions[res.username] = socket;
    socket.emit('dootherthings');
}

const eventafterloggingin = (socket, data)=>{
    const username = getusername(socket);
    sessions[username].emit('eventthatbreaksserver');  //sessions[username] sometimes will be null ?????
}

const disconnect = socket => {
    for(let user in sessions){
        if (socket == sessions[user]){
            delete sessions[user];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace from when this dead socket is attempted to be utilized with an emit:

```
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273286+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app.js:117
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273300+00:00 app[web.1]:                    sessions[username].emit('eventthatbreaksserver');
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273303+00:00 app[web.1]:                                       ^
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273305+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273307+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273315+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:513:12
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273310+00:00 app[web.1]:     at eventafterloggingin (/app/app.js:117:30)
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273312+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.socket.on (/app/app.js:40:30)
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273313+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:159:13)
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273317+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
2018-02-22T04:59:07.273319+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: If you do `eventafterloggingin` before `login` . Nevertheless you should always check that `username` and `sessions[username]` is not undefined.

Comment: It is not actually possible, as the client doesn't allow eventafterloggingin emission before login emission.

Comment: And this is a good usecase for a `WeakMap<socket, user>` ...

Comment: are you shure? And please try to debug it by Logging sockets and the messages of the sockets.

Comment: It is too much data to actually post in here, but this is happening when the server is brought down and then back up, but the clients are still on a specific page with capability without being logged in I believe.

Is there a way on the client to perform an event if it loses connection to the server?

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Might disconnect all of them gracefully before shutting down? E.g. `Object.values(sessions).forEach(socket => socket.disconnect())`